# How to sort text by last column?

Tags: linux, command-line, sorting

This command

```
udisksctl status
```

with Ubuntu 20.04.3 gives:

```
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
SanDisk Extreme           0001      AA010302161107080264 sdb     
ATAPI   DVD A  DH17A3L    8H3D      ATAPI_DVD_A_DH17A3L  sr0     
KINGSTON SA400S27230G     S3Z40107  50016B7683B02C0B     sda     
Optiarc DVD RW AD-7580A   1.04      Optiarc_DVD_RW_AD-7580A sr0     
HL-DT-STDVD-RAM GH22NS30  2.00      HL-DT-STDVD-RAM_GH22NS30 sr0 
Floppy Drive                                             fd0     
Generic Flash Disk        8.07      162194AF             sdc
```

The target is to sort by the last 3 characters in each line (after the header),
giving:

```
Floppy Drive                                             fd0     
KINGSTON SA400S27230G     S3Z40107  50016B7683B02C0B     sda     
SanDisk Extreme           0001      AA010302161107080264 sdb     
Generic Flash Disk        8.07      162194AF             sdc     
Optiarc DVD RW AD-7580A   1.04      Optiarc_DVD_RW_AD-7580A sr0     
ATAPI   DVD A  DH17A3L    8H3D      ATAPI_DVD_A_DH17A3L  sr0     
HL-DT-STDVD-RAM GH22NS30  2.00      HL-DT-STDVD-RAM_GH22NS30 sr0
```

I got partial success with

```
udisksctl status | tail -n+3 | rev | sort -b -k1.1 | rev | grep 'sd\|hd\|fd\|sr\|st'



udisksctl status | tail -n+3
```

from bottom (tail) to line 3
thus cut out 2 line header:

```
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
udisksctl status | tail -n+3 | rev |
```

Reverse, bring last characters in a line to the front of the line.

```
udisksctl status | tail -n+3 | rev | sort -b -k1.1
```

`sort -b` = ignore leading blanks
`-k1.1` = sort via key first letter after ignored blanks

```
udisksctl status | tail -n+3 | rev | sort -b -k1.1 | rev
```

undo reverse

```
udisksctl status | tail -n+3 | rev | sort -b -k1.1 | rev | grep 'sd\|hd\|fd\|sr\|st'
```

Highlight with grep:

- `sd`  Scsi Device
- `hd`  Hard Disk Drive
- `fd`  Floppy Drive
- `sr`  Scsi ROM, cdrom, dvd
- `st`  Scsi Tape Drive
- ...

For simplicity focus on last 3 letters.
The problem is how to do a sort to get:

```
fd0     
sda     
sdb     
sdc     
sr0     
sr0     
sr0
```

Because the problem as shown above is
last 1 letter is sorted not
last 3 letters:

```
fd0     
sr0     
sr0     
sr0     
sda     
sdb     
sdc
```

How can I sort by the last 3 characters in a line? 
(The lines have different lengths.)

Comment: "3 characters" is not the right thing in general. Names like `nvme0n1` may appear.

Comment: Your (failed) solution is both better and worse than you realize.  If your input contains `fd0`, `fd1`, `sr0` and `sr1`, in any order, the output will be `fd0` `sr0` `fd1` `sr1`.  So it is looking at entire last word (not just the last character), but it’s sorting the reversed version of it.  Perhaps a better illustration would be that “cat” and “rat” would be considered to be very close to each other in the sort order, but “cab” and “cat” would be very far apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
udisksctl status | awk '{ print $NF,$0 }' | sort -k1,1 -n | cut -f2- -d' '
```

That takes care also longer strings like `nvme0n1` as sorting is done by last column, not a number of characters.

I don't have udiskctl, but tested by copying your list to a file `sortof`, adding NVM drive to verify and catting the file:

```
pg@TREX:~/test$ cat sortof | awk '{ print $NF,$0 }' | sort -k1,1 -n | cut -f2- -d' '
HL-DT-STDVD-RAM GH22NS30 2.00 HL-DT-STDVD-RAM_GH22NS30 sr0 Floppy Drive fd0
KINGSTON SA400S27230G S3Z40107 50016B7683B02C0B nvme1p
KINGSTON SA400S27230G S3Z40107 50016B7683B02C0B sda
SanDisk Extreme 0001 AA010302161107080264 sdb
Generic Flash Disk 8.07 162194AF sdc
ATAPI DVD A DH17A3L 8H3D ATAPI_DVD_A_DH17A3L sr0
Optiarc DVD RW AD-7580A 1.04 Optiarc_DVD_RW_AD-7580A sr0
```

... so it should work also when you pipe the udiskctl output.

Comment: Peregrino69 posted    udisksctl status | awk '{ print $NF,$0 }' | sort -k1,1 -n | cut -f2- -d' '    and 
it works on Ubuntu 20.04.3 + Ubuntu 16.04.6 + Mint 18.3